# Superset with Impala - Invalid Session id/No protocol version header

Tags: impala, apache-superset

I have Superset using Impala as the main data source. Most of the times, every query runs smoothly and I can build charts and dashboards with ease. I need to generate a Table Chart, containing around 100k records and 30+ columns, but I am having some issues. It is basically a SELECT *, no aggregations, filtering or ordering
are being used.

When the data is relatively big, Superset just throws a bunch of errors (It appears to be that the errors are coming from Impala). But I cannot find any
information regarding those errors. I have tried paginating the results, but it did not worked. Also, when I run the query in Superset Chart page, it doesn't take long, it just
displays the error. The only way some information gets displayed in the Table Chart is when I limit the rows at the "Row limit" option to 10 records. But, this will not work out for me.

Those are the errors that keep ocurring:

```
impala error: Invalid session id: f344bf1aa2a42e2b:ad1df0047d7f909c
impala error: No protocol version header
```

When I use the Oracle connection that I also have, I can generate a table chart from a large amount of records with no problem.

My setup is the following:

```
Impala v3.2.0-cdh6.3.3
Superset v0.36.0
```

So, is that a problem with Superset or Impala? Could have something to with configuration in Superset?